# IDirectSoundBuffer8::SetVolume does not affect the sndvol32 mixer application

Tags: windows, winapi, directx

Microsoft have the following to say on the subject of legacy audio applications:

> In Windows Vista, Sndvol immediately reflects volume changes that an
>   application makes through calls to the IDirectSoundBuffer::SetVolume
>   method or waveOutSetVolume function.

I have found that this is certainly true for the waveOutSetVolume function, but not so for IDirectSoundBuffer8::SetVolume(). The direct sound buffer seems to have its own gain stage that is multiplied with the application volume set in the SndVol mixer.

Can anyone confirm that this is the case, or am I doing something wrong somewhere? Maybe missing a flag or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that IDirectSoundBuffer::SetVolume is an attenuation in 100th of dB, and waveOutSetVolume is a linear scale. Depending on the values you are feeding to both, you might not have the result you are expecting.